# EPPlus not formatting last record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel, epplus

I'm using the helper below to export data from our website into a simple Excel spreadsheet. I use the `CreateAndFormateWorksheet` method to... create and format a worksheet so that all `datetime` data types will be preserved as well as leading zeros.

This works great, however the fomatting isn't being applied to the last row of the spreadsheet.

I've done some research and can't find anything on the topic, so I'm thinking I must have some setting either out of place or used incorrectly. Any ideas?

```
    public static void ExportData<T>(HttpResponseBase Response, List<T> dataSet, string filename)
    {
        var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
        var ws = CreateAndFormatWorksheet(pck, dataSet);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + filename + ".xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    private static ExcelWorksheet CreateAndFormatWorksheet<T>(OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pck, List<T> dataSet)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Monet_Export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(dataSet, true);

        dynamic first = dataSet[0];
        string rowCount = dataSet.Count.ToString();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            string column = columnIndex[i];
            string indexer = column + "2:" + column + rowCount;
            if (info.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                ws.Cells[indexer].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
            }
            else
            {
                // Treat any other column as text to preserve leading 0's
                ws.Cells[indexer].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            }
            i++;
        }

        return ws;
    }
```

Here is a screen shot of the spreadsheet. Notice the `datetime` columns are fomatted correctly in the first two rows, incorrectly in the last.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that with `.LoadFromCollection(dataSet, true);`, the `true` boolean tells it to included a header row which makes your table height = rowcount + 1 for the header line.  So just change it:

```
//+1 for the header line
string rowCount = (dataSet.Count + 1).ToString();
```